# UseCors before UseStaticFiles not works

Tags: javascript, nginx, .net-core, cors

In order to have cors enabled on static files I should have the UseCors call before UseStaticFiles according to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#usecors-and-usestaticfiles-order), unfortunately this doesn't work for me.

#### My situation:

I have a client application that runs on the domain https://example.com and in .net core I have a BE that runs on the domain https://api.example.com both applications are hosted on linux via nginx reverse proxy

CORS for all api calls work fine, however if I try to use javascript from the client application to download an image stored in static files on BE it crashes on the CORS problem. Would anyone know what the problem might be?

###### Nginx configuration looks something like this

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name example.com; 
    root /example.com/www;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         https://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name api.example.com; 
    root /example.com/api;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         https://127.0.0.1:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }   
}
```

###### CORS configuration

```cs
namespace Example
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
                options.ForwardLimit = 2;
                options.KnownProxies.Clear();
                options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("server ip address"));
            });
            services.AddCors(option =>
            {
                option.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
                {
                    builder
                      .WithOrigins("https://example.com", "https://api.example.com")
                      .WithHeaders(["*"])
                      .WithMethods(["GET","POST"])
                      .AllowCredentials()
                      .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains();
                });
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            // ....
            app.UseHsts();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseForwardedHeaders();
            app.UseCors();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            // ....
        }
    }
}
```

###### Code for download image:

```js
new Promise<HTMLImageElement>((resolve, reject) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(image));
    image.addEventListener('error', error => reject(error));
    image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    image.src = "https://api.example.com/files/image.jpg;
  });
```

server is running on .net core 6

Answer (score -1):

I found where was the problem, it's well described here https://www.hacksoft.io/blog/handle-images-cors-error-in-chrome

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).